# Google Maps Api (JavaScript) - Changing the markers using Flex/ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, google-maps, flex3, google-maps-markers

Still kinda new to Flex. I'm trying to customize the Google Javascript API using Flex but I'm having a tough time with what I assumed would've been an easy update.

My map displays a school and all the students who live nearby. I wanted a special marker for the school and then the students can use the default red marker.

I've seen tons of pages that address this in one form or another (like how to change all the markers, or change them via JavaScript or many other formats) but nothing that just simply allows me to change 1 marker on the page to a custom icon using ActionScript/Flex (though frankly, I'd use ANY icon to differentiate it from the other markers.)

As a bonus, I'd change all the default markers to a custom one (different from the school, of course) but if not, that's ok too.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 public function onMapReady(event:MapEvent):void {  
                var dojoGeo:Array = geoSchoolInfoAry;               
                var md:MarkerData = new MarkerData(dojoGeo[0],dojoGeo[1]);
                var latlng:LatLng = new LatLng(md.lat,md.lng);

                var marker:Marker= new Marker(latlng);

                map.setCenter(new LatLng(dojoGeo[0],dojoGeo[1]), 11, MapType.NORMAL_MAP_TYPE);
                map.addControl(new ZoomControl());
                map.addControl(new MapTypeControl());
                map.addControl(new ScaleControl());

                addSchoolMarker(md,marker); 
                addStudentsToMap();  
                }                       

            public function addStudentsToMap():void {              
                for each (var o:Object in geoInfoAC){               
                    var latlngArray:Array = o.split(",");                   
                    var md:MarkerData = new MarkerData(latlngArray[0],latlngArray[1]);
                    var latlng:LatLng = new LatLng(md.lat,md.lng);
                    var marker:Marker= new Marker(latlng);                               
                    addMarker(md,marker);               
                }
            }

            public function addMarker(markerData:MarkerData, marker:Marker):void{               
                var o:Object = {markerData:markerData,marker:marker};
                marker.addEventListener(InfoWindowClosedEvent.NAME,closed);
                markerData.marker = marker;
                map.addOverlay(marker);             
                dataProvider.addItem(o);    
                dataProvider.refresh(); 
            }

                public function closed(event:InfoWindowClosedEvent):void{
                    var marker:Marker = event.marker;
                    var latLng:LatLng = marker.getLatLng();
                    var markerData:MarkerData = new MarkerData(latLng.lat(),latLng.lng());
                    var o:Object = MapUtils.getMarkerDataByLatAndLng(latLng.lat(),latLng.lng(),dataProvider);
                    if (o == null){
                        addMarker(markerData,marker);
                    }else{
                        o["markerData"] = markerData;
                        dataProvider.refresh();
                    }
                }               

            public function addSchoolMarker(markerData:MarkerData, marker:Marker):void{                 
                var o:Object = {markerData:markerData,dojoMarker:marker};
                marker.addEventListener(InfoWindowClosedEvent.NAME,closedSchool);
                markerData.marker = marker;
                map.addOverlay(marker);             
                dataProvider.addItem(o);    
                dataProvider.refresh(); 
            }

            public function closedSchool(event:InfoWindowClosedEvent):void{
                var marker:Marker = event.marker;
                var latLng2:LatLng = marker.getLatLng();
                var markerData:MarkerData = new MarkerData(latLng2.lat(),latLng2.lng());
                var o:Object = MapUtils.getMarkerDataByLatAndLng(latLng2.lat(),latLng2.lng(),dataProvider);
                if (o == null){
                    addSchoolMarker(markerData,marker);
                }else{
                    o["markerData"] = markerData;
                    dataProvider.refresh();
                }
            }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: confused you're using the javascript API you say? if you're using the swc they have deprecated the API, I would suggest moving to a different platform like open street maps or map quest https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/ As far as changing icons goes I know it can be done either way, have done it in AS3 and now in Javascript, in javascript you just specify an {icon:"url/goes/here.png"} in the MarkerOptions passed to the marker constructor.

Comment: I thought the Flash API was deprecated but the JavaScript API was still supported. I'm using it within a Flex project, so I hoped to change the markers through Action-script.

Comment: Well if you're using the swc for google maps then it's not really the "JavaScript API" I know they call it this but the flash client code they give you in the SWC (AS3 classes you're using to create the map etc.) then you're really using an AS3 client making calls to the old JavaScript API.  The flash maps project was always a step or two behind the JavaScript project since it was basically a port I believe.

Comment: For Flash maps I would really look elsewhere like here: http://devblog.mapquest.com/2011/06/21/open-flash-maps-api-with-openstreetmap-support/ if you really feel the need to use Google's maps I would suggest going straight javascript* or target Android/iOS native depending on the situation.

Comment: I do appreciate the suggestion to switch, but the choice of API's was mandated by my boss and client. I'm not sure how to incorporate JavaScript into the action-script code, in order to change the appearance of the markers.

Comment: np.  Anyhow since you're needing to do this in AS3 here's the docs on setting up an icon on a marker in AS3: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/overlays#Icons_Overview says you can use any display object, I actually now recall having used a swf as icons just to try it out and it worked (but is a bit slow).  If you have lots of markers search for Kelvin Luck many marker clusterer. I used it here: http://www.shaunhusain.com/GoogleMapManyMarker/ right click to view source

Comment: Thanks for the links! They helped me tremendously! Here is the code I updated, in case it will help someone in the future:

[Embed(source="Dojo.png")] private var dojoIcon:Class

 public function onMapReady(event:MapEvent):void {
var markerOptions:MarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.icon = new dojoIcon();    
    var dojoMarker:Marker = new Marker(latlng,markerOptions);
    map.addOverlay(marker);